# wp_editor in text mode only(without TinyMCE)

Tags: wp-editor

Is there a way to call `wp_editor` for a meta box using just the text/HTML mode without TinyMCE.  I think the deprecated function pre-3.3 did this but I'm not sure how its done now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to set it to false. The full parameters list is in the file [`wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php#L30).

These are the default values for the **`$settings`** array when calling `wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );`:

```
array(
    'wpautop' => true,
    'media_buttons' => true,
    'textarea_name' => $editor_id,
    'textarea_rows' => 20,
    'tabindex' => '',
    'tabfocus_elements' => ':prev,:next', 
    'editor_css' => '', 
    'editor_class' => '',
    'teeny' => false,
    'dfw' => false,
    'tinymce' => false, // <-----
    'quicktags' => true
);
```

Check the source code for details of each parameter. I've just made a small test with a meta box and works ok.

Comment: For settings description see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/_wp_editors/parse_settings/